# Using Django and Bootstrap Studio together

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-studio

I've recently learned about Bootstrap Studio to create web pages and it looks like a simple and easy tool. I was wondering, if it is possible to generate HTML files and then use those with my Django web app?

Am I just going to waste my time trying to make both those frameworks work together?

Comment: Hello, this is solved now.  Please see my post; are you still needing such a tool?  If yes, then let's connect on the issues forum of BootstrapStudioToDjango.

Answer (score 6):

You are not wasting your time.

I recommend you this links, because I think that you are not completely mastered about model-view-controller.

https://djangobook.com/model-view-controller-design-pattern/
https://medium.com/shecodeafrica/understanding-the-mvc-pattern-in-django-edda05b9f43f

The fully answer of your question is here:

https://www.quora.com/Is-it-easy-to-integrate-Bootstrap-with-Django

Answer (score 2):

Probably to late but there is Github to convert some BootstrapStudio (BSS) export code to a more Django template friendly code see [django-bootstrap-studio-tools](https://github.com/lingster/django-bootstrap-studio-tools)

Haven't used it myself but it looks interesting in you want to use BSS to create a Django Bootstrap template

Comment: django-boostrap-studio-tools with some slighlty improvement, see [bootstrap-studio-to-django-template](https://github.com/AbcSxyZ/bootstrap-studio-to-django-template)

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

https://github.com/enjoysmath/BootstrapStudioToDjango

This is based off of the forked version (see upper-left on GitHub), but it's vastly different and includes a GUI which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see it does a lot. I used it (in conjunction with BSS) to generate the following screencapture of my site:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lp1dGmL8qQk

See other videos on my page, but some of them are actually PyQt5.  Nothing has been released yet and I'm the developer and currently the only user of BootstrapStudioToDjango.

Post in the issues forums, and we'll get you up and running.  Note: this is what's known as a low-to-high code environment.  There's low coding on the BSS side and then high-coding on the JS/Django side.  I've used: https://q.uiver.app, i.e. forked varkor's Quiver on github into my own copy in case I needed to hack it to integrate with my site, and I think I started it out as a git submodule.